# How to load a windows form in new thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

c# .net Winforms,IDE: VS 2010

I having two windows from F1, F2.

F1 is the caller, and F2 is the form which I want to load in thread because it is having lots of rich controls on it.

I am able to load the f2 in child thread but it just get visible and goes, because its on child thread.(See Case 1 Code)

Case 1 Code

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StartProgress();
        Thread th = new Thread(new ThreadStart(LoadForm));
        th.Start();

    }

    private void StartProgress()
    {
        progressBar1.Maximum = 100;
        progressBar1.Step = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            label1.Text = i + "%";
            progressBar1.PerformStep();
            Thread.Sleep(10);
            label1.Refresh();
        }
    }

    private void LoadForm()
    {
        Form2 f2 = new Form2();
        f2.Show();
    }
}
```

Then I did reverse that is I loaded progress bar in child thread and loaded f2 on main thread.(See Case 2 Code)

//Code Case2:
case 2 when progress bar is on child thread.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LoadForm();
    Thread th = new Thread(new ThreadStart(StartProgress));
    th.Start();
    LoadForm();
}

private void StartProgress()
{
    progressBar1.Maximum = 100;
    progressBar1.Step = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
    {
        label1.Text = i + "%";
        progressBar1.PerformStep();
        Thread.Sleep(10);
        label1.Refresh();
    }
}

private void LoadForm()
{
    Form2 f2 = new Form2();
    f2.Show();
}
```

but case 2 having 2 problems.

Problem 1: It loads the f2 as usual with flicking.
Problem 2: Cross Thread Opration progressbar1

//Pls suggest how to load the f2 in background and show it after the progress bar is loaded.

Comment: You don't want to do this.  Having multiple UI threads is a *really* bad idea.  You should have just **one** UI thread, and you should be performing non-UI work asynchronously so as to not block it, rather than blocking your UI thread and trying to compensate through a second UI thread.

Comment: I just want this to remove the flicking in F2 while it loads, I just want to load f2 in background. till the progress bar fills, after that want to show loaded f2 on the screen

Comment: And I'm telling you that you should redesign your application so that you don't have multiple UI threads, and to avoid blocking your main UI thread in the first place.  When you do that your program will be *much* simpler, easier to write/understand, and it will function properly.  Rather than giving you a bucket to try to get the water out of this sinking ship, I suggest you get a ship that doesn't have a hole in it.

Comment: +1 to the question because there is nothing wrong with this question! However, @Servy and others are right. This is effectively impossible, if not just plain impossible. Move background work to a background thread and then load the form in the UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to load a secondary window in the background, a better approach would be to load the data in the background of your current UI and then pass that information to the new Window.

```
    public void btnNewWindow_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.DoWork += WorkerOnDoWork;
        worker.ProgressChanged += WorkerOnProgressChanged;
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += WorkerOnRunWorkerCompleted;
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private List<string> _data = new List<string>();
    private void WorkerOnRunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs runWorkerCompletedEventArgs)
    {
        //Work has finished. Launch new UI from here.
        Form2 f2 = new Form2(_data);
        f2.Show();
    }

    private ProgressBar progressBar1;
    void WorkerOnProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Log process here
    }

    private void WorkerOnDoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        //Perform work you need to load the data.
        for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(50);
            _data.Add("Test" + i);
        }
    }
```

I put this together real quick in WPF but you should be able to make this work with the same principles. I will reiterate that **you shouldn't use a second UI thread**. Load the data up front and then pass along to the window when ready and available.

Comment: Thanks for your effort., I will use this concept where heavy data load is required, But My Form2 F2 is rich of user controls such as Custom Polygons, buttons etc, So one time to design these controls onLoad F2 it flicks on the screen, So I wanted hide this situation with Threads. If you have any other solution u r welcome.

Comment: @user3593678 Well how about splitting the form up into separate tabs and using limited space in your application? Make the users select different tabs so all the UI doesn't have to load at once.

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't have more than one *User Interface (UI)* thread.  The complexity to keep the data between your interface will be quite difficult and often make the application **Not Thread Safe**. Which will cause error after error for you.

The primary goal should keep the *User Interface (UI)* **thread responsive**.  This way as the user interacts with your application the interface is responsive as the application performs computational task.

Here is a great article on keeping your *UI thread responsive* [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh994635.aspx).

You may want to note what Microsoft says here:

> Note:  Not all changes to the UI are necessarily done on the UI thread.
>   There's a separate render thread that can apply UI changes that won't
>   affect how input is handled or the basic layout. For example many
>   animations and transitions that inform users that a UI action has
>   taken place can actually run on this render thread. But if it's your
>   code that is changing UI elements somewhere in your pages, it's best
>   to assume that your code could have the potential to block the UI
>   thread, unless you're familiar with those APIs or subsystems and know
>   for certain they don't affect the UI thread.

---

**Update:**

I didn't realize you were using *Windows Forms*, the article listed above is for *XAML*.  You can use this article to help build a responsive UI with computational task [here](http://reedcopsey.com/2011/11/28/launching-a-wpf-window-in-a-separate-thread-part-1/) for *Windows Forms*. (Link is for WPF, you'll need to port for Windows Forms).

Answer (score -1):

If all you want to do is avoid the flicker, create F2 [as hidden](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/dece45c8-9076-497e-9414-8cd9b34f572f/how-to-start-a-form-in-hidden-mode), and only show it once its initialization is complete.

It's been a while since I did any Windows Forms programming, but I guess you can show the form in your _Load event handler.

Comment: Added a link to an example and some explanation.

Comment: I applied it, it reduced 20% flicking, but 80% is still there.

Comment: When does it happen? Before you hide the form or after you make it visible again?